# 2 for loops into 1

Tags: c++, c++11

I am making a chess game. For movement of the king, you enter the position and the program tells you the moves for the king.

Example: if you enter `A1`, the output is `A2 B1 B2`.

```
for(i=letter-1;i<=letter+1;i++){
for(j=(number-1);j<=(number+1);j++)
```

The thing is, I want these two `for` loops into one `for` loop. Help please, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this little context is impossible to give an accurate answer. But! Here it goes:

```
for(i=letter-1, j=(number-1);i<=letter+1 && j <= (number+1);i++,j++)
```